# How can I speed up my PC for gaming?

Tags: games, performance

I want to make my pc better by adding more graphics and happiness [High Graphics] so by that I want to boost Minecraft, steam and others so I play peacefully without getting annoyed.

- PC type = Linux Ubuntu latest version
- OS Type = 64 bits
- Memory = 1.9 GiB
- Graphics = Intel Q35
- Disk = 118.6 GB

Comment: Please describe the specifications of your PC. Might as well as dumping the output of `lspci`.

Comment: where shall i go?

Comment: done describing

Comment: @Adam Done? What about CPU? And you were asked for the `lspci` command output.

Comment: @Adam your question needs improvement... as already mentioned fe.: lspci output... Motherboard type will be also usefull to know what kind of HW you can improve

Comment: Possible duplicate of OP's self-answered question at https://askubuntu.com/questions/994394/how-to-speed-up-minecraft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try improving your RAM capacity. Nowadays, most of the games are designed with high graphics which require a good amount of RAM for executing. Improving your RAM will support them to run smoothly.

Comment: Unless they also require powerful graphics in which case no matter how much RAM it has the games will still perform poorly or not at all.